# Searching nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, hash

These is sample response of hashes in ruby.

Eg:-

`find abcd1234`

should give me

i was able to find by but it's not sufficent

I have response of sth like these and list keep on going different value but same structure

```
[
  {
    "addon_service": {
      "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
      "name": "heroku-postgresql"
    },
    "config_vars": [
      "FOO",
      "BAZ"
    ],
    "created_at": "2012-01-01T12:00:00Z",
    "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    "name": "acme-inc-primary-database",
    "plan": {
      "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
      "name": "heroku-postgresql:dev"
    },
    "app": {
      "id"=>"342uo23iu4io23u4oi2u34", 
      "name"=>"heroku-staging"},
    },
    "provider_id": "abcd1234",
    "updated_at": "2012-01-01T12:00:00Z",
    "web_url": "https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef"
  } .........
]
```

can anyone know how to grab those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate all array element (a hash) and display its content if the hash meet your requirement:

```
element_found = 0

YOUR_DATA.each do |element|
  if element["provider_id"].match(/abcd1234/)
    element_found += 1
    puts "addon_service: #{element['addon_service']['name']}"
    puts "app: #{element['app']['name']}"
  end
end

if element_found == 0 puts "Sorry match didn't found"
```

Comment: undefined method `provider_id` i don't think so we can do that way

Comment: so you data is actually an array contain hash object or a string of array?

Comment: Undefined method `addon_service`

Comment: I think so it should be inside array

Comment: @Gandalf have you updated all of my code? I use hash style `element['addon_service']['name']`, there is no method here.

Comment: Two thing.
I have some of provider id like abcd1234, abc, abc34..etc it shows all those result can't it be more specifics like find only `abcd1234`?
And can i pass variable inside `/provider_id/`?
i want to make provider_id able to to take input

Comment: yes for both question. so what exactly you want to find? display all hash has `provide_id` with pattern `abc` or just equal exactly: "abcd1234"?

Comment: i want to find only "abcd1234"

Comment: yeah so it will be: `if element["provider_id"] == abcd1234`. And for 2nd question, you can do it by replacing `abcd1234` with your variable: `if element["provider_id"] == your_variable`

Comment: Just check ur snippet i have added else..the problem is it's iterating and printing lot's of same puts...

Comment: @Gandalf I don't understand your question? can you more specific why you add the `else`?

Comment: So what happen if u don't find match it shows nth? I want to make alert by "Match didn't found" but it iterating on every block

Comment: you can count the number of match, then if count == 0, display "Sorry match didn't found". Btw, I have updated the answer according to your request

Comment: And also it's printing even if match is found

Comment: I think it's off topic now. Can you open new question so it will be more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements of the array are hashes you can select the appropriate ones by matching the desired key.

```
select {|app| app[:provider_id] == "abcd1234"}
```

Do you know what to do with the element once you select it?
I think you want some of the items from the hash, but not all of them.
That might look like:

```
select {|app| app[:provider_id] == "abcd1234"}.map {|app| app.select {|key, v| [:addon_service, :app].include?(key) } }
```

Comment: It's returning empty `[]`